# $subtract aggregation operation in MongoDB causing page not to load

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm pretty new to javascript. I'm trying to create a dashboard for a website. I want the dashboard to show how many orders are unfullfilled. I was able to get the fullfilled orders to show, but when I try to use $subtract to get the unfullfilled orders by subtracting the number of fullfilled from the total number of orders my page no longer loads. I would really appreciate any help or guidance on this issue. Thank you.

My code for unfullfilled orders:

```
  const unfullfilled = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          fullfill: { $sum: '$shippedValue' },
          orders: { $sum: 1 },
          unfullfill: {$subtract:['$orders','$fullfill']},
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Dashboard display portion:

```
<li>
   <div className="summary-title color2">
      <span>
        <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart" />Unfullfilled
      </span>
   </div>
   <div className="summary-body">
     {summary.unfullfilled[0] ? summary.unfullfilled[0].unfullfill : 0}
   </div>
</li>
```

My code for the fullfilled orders:

```
 const fullfilled = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          fullfill: { $sum: '$shippedValue' },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Dashboard display portion:

```
<li>
       <div className="summary-title color2">
          <span>
            <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart" />Fullfilled
          </span>
       </div>
       <div className="summary-body">
          {summary.fullfilled[0] ? summary.fullfilled[0].fullfill : 0}
       </div>
</li>
```

Comment: You can try calculating `unfullfill` in a following `$addFields` or `$project` stage.

Comment: I had tried something like that previously, and it didn't work. I just tried `$addFields: {unfullfill: {$subtract:['$orders','$fullfill']}, },` and  `$project: { unfullfill: {$subtract:['$orders','$fullfill']}, }, ` following the `$group: {}` again and neither worked.

Comment: Have you checked what are the values of 'orders' and 'fullfill' after the `$group` stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$subtract` with `$group` as `$subtract` is not an accumulator operator.

You can use a `$project` stage

```
 const unfullfilled = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          fullfill: { $sum: '$shippedValue' },
          orders: { $sum: 1 }
        },
      },
      {
        $project:{
          fullfill:1,
          orders:1,
          unfullfill: {$subtract:['$orders','$fullfill']}
        }
      }
    ]);
```